# Using custom WCF in SharePoint hosted App

Tags: 2013, wcf, 403, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have been trying since a few days to call a custom made WCF service from a SharePoint Hosted App. I have read all over the information available on forums and I couldn't find a working solution.

When I call my custom WCF service from a test console app, it works perfectly. Although, when I call it withing a SharePoint Hosted App, I get a "403 Forbidden" Error. I read it has to do with the fact that the AppWeb and the HostWeb are in a different domain.

So I tried the "cross-domain" JS Library, but I had no luck to get this working.

I might be doing something wrong, maybe some of you can help...

Here is the code I used in my ap to call the Service:

```
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;

$(document).ready(function () {
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getParameterByName('SPHostUrl'));
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getParameterByName('SPAppWebUrl'))

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", CallService);
});

function CallService()
{
var exec;
exec = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
exec.executeAsync(
    {
        url: appweburl + "/_vti_bin/CSN.DataService/DataService.svc/GetData?query=QueryHere",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) { alert('Error: ' + errorMessage); }
        });
}
```

Even with the Cross-Domain Library, I still get a 403 Forbidden error.

I have also tried to add read rights in my app to the site collection level.

I have edited the AppManifest.xml to add an app principal (which I found on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx)

```
<AppPrincipal>
    <Internal AllowedRemoteHostUrl="~remoteAppUrl" />
</AppPrincipal>
```

All of that didn't work so far. Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around.

I deployed my custom WCF to IIS instead of deploying it into SharePoint (ISAPI). I had to make the WCF service public (to be able to call it cross-domain) by adding this code into the WCF's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I then deployed the WCF to IIS and from there I have been able to call if from a standard Jquery Ajax Call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://services.ca/SQLService/DataService.svc/GetData?query=query",
        dataType: 'json',
        processdata: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            var JSONmsg = JSON.stringify(msg);

            var Response = document.getElementById('ServiceResponse');
            Response.innerText = JSONmsg;


        },
        error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            alert('Error: ' + errorMessage);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we write a code to read audit logs in wcf service for SharePoint online? So I want to pass a url of page that user visited to a wcf service and wcf service then gets audit logs based on passed url. Is it possible?